# Orthonormal basis of the subspace $2x-y+3z=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given: subspace U: $2x-y+3z=0$

I should calculate an orthonormal basis for U.
If the subspace is given as a span, I know how to approach.

But how can I convert the equation above, to a span with the form

$L=((…),(…), (...))$?

Comment: Do you know how to find a basis for a subspace of the form $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax = 0\}$?

Comment: Hint: 

1) Find the dimension of U.

2) Find a vector in U.

3) normalize this vector with the help of: $u_{\text{normalized}} = \dfrac{u}{||u||}$, where $u \in U$.

I think [This][1]  might also interest you.


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: I know the whole gram schmidt process with subspaces given as exlpicit spans. But I don't know how to convert implicitly given subspace to an explicit form aka spans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

Plane can be spanned by two vectors. Let $P_1=(3,0,-2)$ and $P_2=(0,3,1)$ then notice that  $P_1,P_2$ live on the plane so they must spane the plane. You know how to procede from there.

Comment: how i know i need only 2 vectors? I know the rule that a subspace in  $R^n$ has to contain always $n-1$ vectors. Does this rule apply everywhere?

Comment: @SuperNova: first way, by knowing plane has two dimension. second way, there is one equation, three unknown which means there are two independent variable which conclude the result.